# c# strip rss description for html using Argotic Syndication Framework

Tags: c#, html, rss

I am using `Argotic Syndication Framework` to parse a rss-feed into feed items. However I need to strip the description for all html.

The following shows an example of a rss feed description.

```
Jeg blev i maj inviteret til at holde et oplæg som keynote speaker på en konference i Alaska i HETL-regi (The International Higher Education Teaching and Learning Association). Patrick Blessinger, stifteren af HETL, har netop medvirket i et amerikansk online radio &#8230; <a href="http://aesbrock.wordpress.com/2013/07/12/niels-brock-naevnt-i-amerikansk-radio-interview/">Læs resten <span class="meta-nav">&#8594;</span></a><img alt="" border="0" src="http://stats.wordpress.com/b.gif?host=aesbrock.wordpress.com&#038;blog=978571&#038;post=4538&#038;subd=aesbrock&#038;ref=&#038;feed=1" width="1" height="1" />
```

I want it just to be shown as text without the html.

I tried using the following regular expression

```
Regex.Replace(item.Description, @"<(.|\n)*?>", string.Empty);
```

but that is not quite right;

I saw suggestion about using `HTMLAgilityPack` but I would like to avoid using external libraries.

Any suggestions are highly appreciated.

Comment: how about this: `Regex.Replace(item.Description, "<.*?>", string.Empty);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the suggestion Pete, but it still left some of the html. I ended up doing it like this.

```
HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(Regex.Replace(item.Description, @"<!--[\S\s]*?-->|<(?:"".*?""|'.*?'|[\S\s])*?>", ""));
```

Its from a post(somewhere on the webz), but I did not bookmark it, so if anyone recognizes it - thank you :) I hope it can help someone else.